# How properties files loaded using Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm curious to know how apllication.properties file or any other property files get loaded using Spring.

Here is XML to do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id = "myProperties"  
         class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
         <list>
            <value>classpath*:application.properties</value>
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>  
</beans>
```

As you can see the `application.properties` file is getting loaded using the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class.

And `locations` is an instance variable of type `Resource` in class `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. So the value in above example `classpath*:application.properties` is an instance name of class which implements Resource interface. Is it correct?

If yes, then after that, how further loading of files happens in spring backend ?

Can anyone share please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right and this the corresponding java code for xml config, After loading properties files into spring environment. By using `java.reflection` spring will inject the values into spring beans.

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer myProperties() {
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc
  = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]
  { new ClassPathResource( "application.properties" ) };
ppc.setLocations( resources );
ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
return ppc;
}
```

Comment: You mean to say myProperties instance of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer calls automatically properties()  (you mentioned) method in spring framework .. ? The moment XML compiles ..!

Comment: i think you misunderstood, spring will load this `xml` and creates `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with name `myProperties` (This bean is useful to register bean in JMX) @Jon

Comment: May I know please how did you know the code you have mentioned is exeuted once xml is loaded by Spring .. ? Is it written in framework .. ? Just curious to know ..! :)

Comment: This code is a reflection of xml what you have, your question is not really clear for me @j